# Combining local processes with remote processes in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, remote-process

I'm trying to use remote processes in conjuntion with local processes, but when I do I get the following output

```
julia> addprocs(["user@host"], tunnel=true, dir="~/julia-79599ada44/bin/", sshflags=`-p 6969`)
id: cannot find name for group ID 350
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 2

julia> addprocs(23)
fatal error on 2: ERROR: connect: host is unreachable (EHOSTUNREACH)
 in wait at ./task.jl:284
 in wait at ./task.jl:194
 in stream_wait at stream.jl:263
 in wait_connected at stream.jl:301
 in Worker at multi.jl:113
 in anonymous at task.jl:905
fatal error on fatal error on 5: 6: fatal error on fatal error on fatal error on 9: 14: 8: Worker 3 terminated.
...
```

I have tried adding the local processes first but I get the same errors when I add the remote ones.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is old, but I was asked today if I knew the answer of this unanswered question.

You could use the `-p` along with the `--machinefile` options:

> Julia can be started in parallel mode with either the `-p` or the `--machine-file` options. `-p` n will launch an additional n worker processes, while `--machine-file` file will launch a worker for each line in file file. The machines defined in file must be accessible via a **password-less** ssh login, with Julia installed at the **same** location as the current host. Each machine definition takes the form `[count*][user@]host[:port] [bind_addr[:port]]`. user defaults to current user, port to the standard ssh port. `count` is the number of workers to spawn on the node, and defaults to 1. The optional bind-to `bind_addr[:port]` specifies the IP address and port that other workers should use to connect to this worker.

It has been a long time since I used the `--machinefile` option, in my case the `n` option didn't work and I don't know if it has been fixed, but you could add one line for each worker process you want instead, for example, if this doesn't work for you:

```rb
# machinefile.txt
23 user@host
```

You could try this:

```rb
# machinfile.txt
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
user@host
```

And then invoke julia like:

```
$ julia -p 2 --machinefile machinefile.txt
```

For a total of 25 processes (2 local and 23 remote).

But the `n` option should work if it is documented, else please check if there is a bug and if not, open a new one.