# Adding processes to two different remote hosts

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have several servers that I'm planning to use to run some simulations in Julia. The problem is, I can only add remote processes to a single server. If i try to add the processes to the next server I get an error. This is what I'm trying to do and what I get

```
addprocs(["user@host1"], tunnel=true, dir="~/julia-483dbf5279/bin/", sshflags=`-p 6969`)    
addprocs(["user@host2"], tunnel=true, dir="~/julia-483dbf5279/bin/", sshflags=`-p 6969`)
id: cannot find name for group ID 350
fatal error on 6: ERROR: connect: host is unreachable (EHOSTUNREACH)
 in wait at ./task.jl:284
 in wait at ./task.jl:194
 in stream_wait at stream.jl:263
 in wait_connected at stream.jl:301
 in Worker at multi.jl:113
 in anonymous at task.jl:905
Worker 6 terminated.
```

The host is reachable and I can connect to it via ssh. I had a similar problem when adding local processes, as I explained in this stackoverflow question:

[Combining local processes with remote processes in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333529/combining-local-processes-with-remote-processes-in-julia)

Comment: I found a discussion on this same problem here https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/6256. Apparently the processes need direct visibility without ssh tunneling, which is not possible in my case. Does anyone known an alternative way to add the processes to the hosts?